# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'. Why i am getting this error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Why i am unable to use click function inside my class

```
# from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
# from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#
# options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
#
# driver.get("https://python.org")
# print(driver.title)


####
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from  selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import RFOS

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
#driver = RFOS.OpenBrowser('chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)



class SetWindow():
    def test(self):
        url = RFOS.fetchDataFromPropertiesFile("Credentials.properties","Login", "url_ChatGpt")
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(60)


        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grouped-demo']").click()






        #search = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="q")

        #search.send_keys("Hey, Tecadmin")
        #search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

ChatGpt = SetWindow()
ChatGpt.test()

time.sleep(123)
driver.close()
```

I wanted to click on search bar of https://www.futurepedia.io/

**Unidentified error. Whenever i want to perform click function on searchbar of any website by using this code it throws this kind of error.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZyye.png): error

Comment: *driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grouped-demo']")* is returning None.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grouped-demo']")
```

appears to return `None`. You're then attempting to call `.click()` on it, which fails.

You just need to add some handling for the case it returns `None`. Something like:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grouped-demo']")
if element is None:
    # Handle None case
    ...
else:
    element.click()
```